# Not able to push the form data in to the ember store

Tags: ember.js

this is my controller code 
       **controllers/new-user.js**

```
   import Ember from 'ember';
   export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   actions:{
      register:function(){
        var person=this.store.createRecord('person'{
         firstName:fname,
         lastName:sname,
         email:email,
         password:password,
         confirmPassword:confirmPassword
        });
        person.save();
     }
   }
   });
```

I am working with ember-cli and i am new to ember so could  you please tell me what is wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

First there is to notice you should not use `Ember.ObjectController` but directly extend `Ember.Controller`. Checkout the [deprecation](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_objectcontroller).

Next all your variables `fname`, `sname` and so on are not declared. Probably you want to access the attributes on the controller. So either do this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {get} = Ember;

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    register(){
      let person = this.store.createRecord('person', {
        firstName:get(this, 'fname'),
        lastName:get(this, 'sname'),
        email:get(this, 'email'),
        password:get(this, 'password'),
        confirmPassword:get(this, 'confirmPassword')
      });
      person.save();
    }
  }
});
```

Or use `.getProperties`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {get} = Ember;

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    register(){
      let person = this.store.createRecord('person', this.getProperties(
        'fname',
        'sname',
        'email',
        'password',
        'confirmPassword'
      ));
      person.save();
    }
  }
});
```

---

However my personal recommendation is to call `createRecord` in the `model` hook of the route and then directly bound your template to your model. Later just call `.save()` in your action.

Comment: Now also  I am not getting any output in the browser.If i created a model hook how it will connect to the controller action?.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Can you provide a not working [ember-twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com/)?

Comment: I am not getting any errors but my index page is not displayed.

Comment: can you tell me how to connect this controller action to model hook?.

Comment: If i replaced the ObjectController with Controller i got the output but i want to know how to conncect this action to a modelhook.

Comment: You don't connect it. You create the model in the `model()` hook of the route, and later when the user submits the form or so you trigger the action and save the model. However for this kind of discussion maybe checkout the IRC or slack channel.

Comment: The ember data is not a permanent storage i want to store and retrieve the data from my mysql database.Can u suggest any tutorial or book that i can fallow to achieve it.

Comment: Well, this not not ember topic. Use the backend framework of your choice and create a JSONAPI for ember-data.